# Pospone reminder on outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, reminder

When I set a reminder on outlook it gives me the possibility to postpone it.  The default interval to postpone the reminder is 5 minutes, but it is always too short, is it possible to set another automatic time interval?

I know that is possible to choose another interval by menu, but if is possible to set another one is is better

I useo office 2007 on windows 7

Answer (score 3):

You can select which options is default bu going to:

Tools > Options > Calendar > Preferences > Default Reminder:
[image]

Unfortunately, this is as far as it goes - there is no way to change the option list as far as I am aware.